# Параметризация темплейта типом возвращаемого значения

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Я хочу странного.
я хочу написать класс, в котором есть метод, который на вход принимает функцию и набор её аргументов, вызывает её, и возвращает значение вызыванной функции.

При этом я проделал следующий эксперимент. Вот есть простейшая функция

```
    int Add(const int& x, const int& y){
        cout << "x+y = " << x+y << endl;
        return x+y;
    };
```

Теперь я попробую её вызвать.
Для начала - просто вызвать, не возвращая ничего.
Тогда всё довольно просто:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class MyCaller{
    public:
        template <typename SomeFunction,  typename... Args>
        void MyCall(SomeFunction func, const Args&... args);
    };

    template <typename SomeFunction, typename... Args>
    void MyCaller::MyCall(SomeFunction func, const Args&... args){
        func(args...);
    };

    int Add(const int& x, const int& y){
        cout << "x+y = " << x+y << endl;
        return x+y;
    };

    int main(){
        MyCaller mycaller;
        mycaller.MyCall ( Add, 1, 2 );
    }
```

При запуске происходит вызов, печатается контрольная строка "x+y = 3"

Но стоит мне добавить в параметры темплейта еще и тип возвращаемого значения, как я начинаю получать при компиляции ошибку "error: no matching function for call to 'MyCaller::MyCall(int (&)(const int&, const int&), int, int)'":

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class MyCaller{
    public:
        template <typename SomeFunction, typename RetType, typename... Args>
        RetType MyCall(SomeFunction func, const Args&... args);
    };

    template <typename SomeFunction, typename RetType, typename... Args>
    RetType MyCaller::MyCall(SomeFunction func, const Args&... args){
        return func(args...);
    };

    int Add(const int& x, const int& y){
        cout << "x+y = " << x+y << endl;
        return x+y;
    };

    int main(){
        MyCaller mycaller;
        auto x = mycaller.MyCall ( Add, 1, 2 );
    }
```

Как я понимаю, проблема возникает из за того, что компилятор не знает на этапе компиляции, что именно я буду возвращать из темплейтной функции.
Не проблема, я готов явным образом передать тип возвращаемого значения в качестве одного из аргументов при вызове, что то  типа

```
    auto x = mycaller.MyCall ( Add, type_info::typeid(Add), 1, 2 );
```

Но вот как это использовать в темплейте - не могу понять.

Не подскажете ли, как это можно сделать?

Спасибо!

Дополнение, написанное после ответа на вопрос.

Господа,
мне **HolyBlackCat** дал великолепный, просто потрясающий совет, который и есть ответ, и за который ему большое спасибо.

Здесь я привожу пример того, как класс стал выглядеть после этого - просто для полноты картины:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class MyCaller{
    public:
        template <typename SomeFunction, typename... Args>
        decltype(auto) MyCall(SomeFunction func, const Args&... args);
    };

    template <typename SomeFunction, typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) MyCaller::MyCall(SomeFunction func, const Args&... args){
        return func(args...);
    };

    int Add(const int& x, const int& y){
        cout << "x+y = " << x+y << endl;
        return x+y;
    };

    string Concatenate(const string& s1, const string& s2){
        return s1 + s2;
    }

    int main(){
        MyCaller mycaller;
        auto x = mycaller.MyCall ( Add, 1, 2 );
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;

        auto y = mycaller.MyCall ( Concatenate, "Hello,", "world!" );
        cout << "y = " << y << endl;

    }
```

Я доволен как слон, потому, что это позвоялет мне самому ответить на один мучающий меня вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы просто заменил `void MyCall(...)` на `decltype(auto) MyCall(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Указывать явно точно так же, как и для других шаблонов:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyCaller {
    template<typename RetType, typename SomeFunction, typename... Args>
    RetType MyCall(SomeFunction func, const Args& ... args);
};

template<typename RetType, typename SomeFunction, typename... Args>
RetType MyCaller::MyCall(SomeFunction func, const Args& ... args) {
    return func(args...);
};

int Add(const int& x, const int& y) {
    std::cout << "x+y = " << x + y << '\n';
    return x + y;
};

int main() {
    MyCaller mycaller;
    auto x = mycaller.MyCall<int>(Add, 1, 2);
}
```

Только порядок параметров надо поменять, чтобы не указывать тип функции явно, ведь это не нужно.